# Resolve get request error caused by .populate()

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am trying to make a get request to  my database. I have a collection called products and another called categories. My get request contains a .populate():

```
export async function GET(req: Request, { params }: Params) {
  await mongooseConnect();

  const { id } = params;

  try {
    const product = await Product.findById(id).populate("category");
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(product), { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("didnt work for some reason");
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(error), { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

If I remove the .populate("category") part, the GET request works (although I only get the category ID back instead of all the fields I need for the category. When I include .populate("category"), I get a 500 error. I am constantly having issues with .populate(). Thoughts on how to resolve this?

Here is the product model:

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  category: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category" },
  description: { type: String },
  price: { type: Number, require: true },
  images: { type: [String] },
  availability: { type: Object },
});

export const Product =
  mongoose?.models?.Product || mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

Here is the category model:

```
const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  parentCategory: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category" },
  properties: [{ type: Object }],
});

export const Category =
  mongoose?.models?.Category || mongoose.model("Category", CategorySchema);
```

Comment: What's the error that results in the `500` return status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In next.js i faced the the same thing i was getting an error every time i use populate the fix of this is just to import the model in any page you use as a ref like in your example if you are using ref: "Category" in the product model make sure to import Category model in this page and this will apply to any page you use the ref

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I ended up doing. I should have posted the answer but I got too busy. Accepting your answer now!